# Getting parsing error while writting custom grok filter

Tags: logstash-grok, grok

I am new to regex and using logstack grok filter. I have to write my own regex to filter this message

`NAID-iOS-3093448A-BC34-4FE1-A057-29AD2CEF8FD3-1471410782.565937 IP-202.174.93.103 2016-08-17 00:13:09,963`

my grok filter is

```
grok{
   match => {"message" => "%{DATA:deviceid}%{IP:Serverip}%{%{YEAR}[-]%{MONTHNUM}[-]%{MONTHDAY}:Date}%{GREEDYDATA:data}"}
}
```

the default `DATE_EU` entry in grok has `%{MONTHDAY}[./-]%{MONTHNUM}[./-]%{YEAR}`

but i needed a reverse of it so I wrote

`%{%{YEAR}[./-]%{MONTHNUM}[./-]%{MONTHDAY}:Date}` instead of `%{DATE_EU:Date}` but getting `[0]_grok parsefailure` message in my syntax.

I even followed https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#_custom_patterns and created a patterns directory inside logstash folder I am using windows and added `DATE_LOG %{YEAR}[./-]%{MONTHNUM}[./-]%{MONTHDAY}` entry inside file named "extra" but again got `parsing_error`.

Answer (score 0):

You're using bad syntax. While parsing a log line you name each part with your own variables, for example:

```
%{MONTHNUM:month}-%{MONTHDAY:day}
```

and then you complete your own format this way:

```
replace => ['timestamp', '%{month}-%{day}']
```